# Cannot create filter for AD based on whether or not a device is disabled

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently trying to use the following to pull a list of servers that are not disabled.

```
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objsearcher.Filter = "(&(OperatingSystem=Window*Server*)(Enabled -eq $true))"
```

My issue is that this is not a valid search filter.

I've done alot of searching, and cannot find a way to filter for whether a device is enabled or disabled, like I'm attempting to above.

I'm aware that I should be able to do it via:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'
```

But was hoping to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.petri.com/find-disabled-and-inactive-active-directory-users-accounts-with-powershell-revisited):

```
$objsearcher.Filter = "(&(OperatingSystem=Window*Server*)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

If you wanted to search for *disabled* instead, remove the `!` operator:

```
$objsearcher.Filter = "(&(OperatingSystem=Window*Server*)(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

Comment: Thanks mate that solved it :) out of curiosity, if I wanted to invert it to only search for disabled any idea how I'd achieve that ?

Comment: See my edit and also have a look at the source in the link.